# Remote shutdown not working in Python

Tags: python, cmd, system-shutdown

I'm trying to write up a small script using Python 2.7.7 that would ping an IP address and determine whether that PC is turned on or off, and change the power state of that system accordingly. I'm relying heavily on the Python modules `subprocess` and `wakeonlan`. I am not having any issues pinging or using WOL, but the shutdown functionality is behaving in a very strange way.

Using the command `shutdown -s -t 0 /m \\XXX.XXX.X.X` from the command prompt works fine, as well as the following from the Python interactive shell in cmd:

```
import subprocess
ip = 'XXX.XXX.X.X'   # use for example
subprocess.call('shutdown -s -t 0 /m \\\\%s' % ip)
```

But running the same command in from a Python script is returning this error:

> `XXX.XXX.X.X`: The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then try again or contact your system administrator.(53)

Are there any background behaviors that I'm not thinking about? Perhaps something to do with the subprocess module? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/)? There is a description of [`win32api.InitiateSystemShutdown`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__InitiateSystemShutdown_meth.html) on Tim Golden's site that looks like it should work. The signature is `InitiateSystemShutdown(computerName, message, timeOut, bForceClose, bRebootAfterShutdown)`.

Comment: And there is [a post on the blog Mouse vs. Python called Restarting PCs with Python](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/27/restarting-pcs-with-python/) on this topic with an example using pywin32.